# Batch file Robocopy

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I'm trying to automate to copy a file from drive c: to drive d, I did it by writing a batch code and scheduling it to run in task scheduler. my problem is every-time my batch run it over write the existing file in the drive d. Is it possible to keep the old file and auto name the new file with the current date. for example when the batch run the file.xlsx in the c:\test will copy to d:\test as file13012014.xlsx.

@echo off
robocopy  C:\Test D:\test\ file.xlsx /S /B /ZB /R:4 /A-:H /W:10 /tee /LOG:"d:\logtest1.txt"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off robocopy C:\Test D:\test\ file.xlsx /S /B /ZB /R:4 /A-:H /W:10 /tee /LOG:"d:\%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%.xlsx"
```

*MAY* work for you. It depends a lot on your date format.

`%date:~7,2%` means "take the date string, from the 7th character (counting from "character 0") for 2 characters for instance. This will work for `Wed 01/14/2014` format producing 14012014.

What it would be for **your** date format - well you'd need to tell us what that is. And you'd need to be aware that it's possible to have spaces in place of leading zeroes, which is an extra complication.

```
echo %date%
```

will show you the date. Choose your substrings from there. You may need to use a dummy variable if you're using leading-zero suppression.

```
set "dummy=%date: =0"
echo %dummy%
```

**or** you may need to process the date in a more sophisticated manner - all depends on the date-format.

ANd talking of formats, you may prefer to produce your filenames as `yyyymmdd.xlsx` because that way there's no ambiguity (is it ddmmyy or mmddyy - local convention varies) and it means that an alphabetical sort on name is a chronlogical sort on name.

There are hundreds of articles on SO about processing dates in batch to which you can refer.

---

Argh. I see. `robocopy` is oriented towards mass-copy so rename-destination-file appears to be not-included (I also dislike having to say `U:` to mean `U:\` as a source directory - `U:` qould seem to me to mean `U:.`)

ANyhow, here's a possibility:

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "sourcefile=firelast.xtx"
SET "logfile=u:\logtest1.txt"

robocopy "%sourcedir%" "%destdir%\%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%" "%sourcefile%" /B /ZB /R:4 /A-:H /W:10 /tee /LOG:"%logfile%"
MOVE "%destdir%\%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%\%sourcefile%" "%destdir%\%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%.xlsx"
RD "%destdir%\%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%"


GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` etc. to suit your circumstances. I used settings to suit my system.

I also use just plain `dd/mm/yyyy` as my date format, hence my substring settings are likely to be different to yours.

I've removed th `/s` from the `robocopy` options as it seems to serve no purpose here.

Essentially, this creates a new subdirectory at the destination naed (date) then `moves` the file to the new name in the destination directory and deltes the (date) directory generated.

If you didn't want all the logging palaver, then a simple `copy` with destination filename constructed according to the same formula would probably be better (IMHO, anyway...)

Comment: Hi Mr. Magoo, As an example i want the saved file as filename13012014.xlsx instead of just filename.xlsx The one that you showed is saving the log as xlsx, but i dont want the log i only want the file to save with the date on the end of the file so that it will not overwrite the existing file on drive d.

Comment: Hi again Mr. Magoo, the above code created this path and the folder is empty D:\Tu 0\13. I dont know what happened.

Comment: As I've pointed out more than once, the processing of `%date%` depends on **YOUR** date format. I don't know what **YOUR** date format is, but I'd conclude that it's `Tue 01/13/2015`. In that case, you need to change the date gymnastics from `%date:~0,2%%date:~3,2%%date:~6,4%` to `%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%`wherever it appears.